# DIR function not printing all file name

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code to list all file names inside a same folder, my code is working also but problem is that it is leaving one file. suppose there is 10 files in folder and I run macro it is printing only 9 names in immediate window. Pls correct me where I am wrong in the code below

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim curpath As String, path As String

    path = "H:\NAFIS STUDY\Excel vba\New Folder\"

    curpath = Dir(path)

    Do Until curpath = vbNullString Or curpath = ""
        Debug.Print Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

I think I am not using `DIR` function correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this, i.e. use your variable `curpath` to write to the debug output and then assign the next return value of `Dir` to it. In the original code the first return value of `Dir(path)` was never printed as you never printed out `curpath`

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim curpath As String, path As String

    path = "c:\\temp\\"

    curpath = Dir(path)

    Do Until curpath = vbNullString Or curpath = ""
        Debug.Print curpath
        curpath = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need for both `curpath = vbNullString` and `curpath = "" to exit the loop.

Comment: Yeah but I didn't want to refactor his whole code but show him the mistake which lead to the unexpected result. Good point though

Comment: Personal preference I would have removed it but no worries

Comment: Thanks a lot sir both of you, my code is working now Yeah!